# How to get items on one square platforms?

Tags: dungeons-of-dredmor

How to get items on the ground on one square platforms like this one?

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The following abilities let you reach these:

- **Artful Dodger** grants *Knightly Leap* at level 2 which lets you jump like a chess knight
- **Psionics** grants *Psychokinetic Shove* at level 2 which lets you push the item off that platform
- **Mathemagic** grants *Froda's Jump Discontinuity* at level 1 which randomly teleports you a short distance, so it might take a while to get there. On level 5 you get *Xeuclid's Translation* a more expensive but non-random teleport.
- **Ley Lines** grants *Invisible Geometries* at level 5. It lets you move in cardinal directions, but costs a ton of mana. This skill is especially useful in wizard builds.

Comment: The "Artful Dodger" branch grants the "Knightly Leap" trick at level 2 - lets you jump like a chess knight, and works for grabbing these.

Comment: @DMA57361: Good call, I've edited it in.

Comment: I tried Artful Dodger, I don't know why but I cannot jump over it

Comment: @Drake: It seems you can't do every legal knight move. If you hold down the right mouse button you can see where you'd land if you release the mouse. Try approaching form another side if the move you want to do isn't possible for some reason.

Comment: You can also use one of the maces move, I can't remember which level it is, which move enemies and items on two squares in front of you. You can push it of the platform with this.

Comment: @Drake, apparently this will be fixed in patch 1.0.3: http://www.gaslampgames.com/blog/2011/07/19/patch-1-0-3-update/

Comment: @yatima2975 Ah ok, it was a bug :)

Comment: Would **Move in Mysterious Ways** from the **Burglery** skill work?

Comment: Yes, doesn't the Burglary skill have a teleport ability?

Comment: You can also use the new skill from Ley Walker maximum rank to teleport there. This skill lets you move like a rook in chess.

Comment: You can also push items around with the first skill from Clockwork Knight skill. Works to push these items across water. Hell, it pushes mobs through walls and doors.

Answer (score 4):

Use a concussion bomb.

You make it with the tinker kit, the recipe is something like:

> 1 × Gunpowder → Makeshift Bomb(s)
>   *Does not require any Tinker skill (requires level 0).*
>   *Higher skill creates more bombs, up to a max of 6*

Then

> 2 × Makeshift Bomb → Concussion Bomb(s)
>   *Requires Tinkerer Skill level 1 or higher.*
>   *Higher skill creates more bombs, up to a max of 3*

Answer (score 2):

There's lots of ways.  Any effect that delivers knockback, from Ragnar's Meteor to Grey Heron Takes Flight to the aforementioned Concussion Bomb to Barometric Pulse Device to a carefully-arranged Handy Wand (have to hit a flying monster hovering on the water between you and the item) can do it.  IIRC, you can even do it with Unliving Wall, which gives knockback so that monsters don't get trapped under it. :)

Any effect that allows you to teleport can do it (Knightly Leap is the fastest one you can get to in terms of leveling up).  Even the more hardcore/obscure teleports like Rocket Jump can get there.  It's not likely you'll ever do it with a blink, but it can be done.

Finally, you can grab it directly with Magical Law's Confiscate Evidence, which lets you pick stuff up from anywhere you can see it.